# How to find elements of an numpy array that are closes to a given target set?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have a numpy array:

`arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,9,11])`

and I would like to find elements of a target array say:

`target = np.array([3,10])`

that are closest to the elements of the original array. So the the results is going to be:

`[3,3,3,3,10,10]`
Because 1,2,3,4 are matched to 3 of the target array and 9,11 were matched to 10.

Is there a function in scipy/numpy to do that?

Comment: No, there is no built-in function.  You'll have to plan out your logical steps and post your code -- if you get stuck.

Comment: @motam79 accept an answer if you think it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct function just for that I think. This one-liner can do what you want.

First select the indices with minimum difference and take the values from target array.

```
arr = target[abs(arr[None, :] - target[:, None]).argmin(axis=0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array([1,2,3,4,9,11])
tar = np.array([3,10])
def target(arr,target):
    ans=np.empty([len(arr)], dtype=int)
    for elem in range(arr.size):
        dist=[]
        for ele in range(target.size):
            dist.append(abs(target[ele]-arr[elem]))
        ans[elem]=target[dist.index(min(dist))]
    return ans

print(target(ar,tar))
```

Hope this helps.